# How to deactivate inline mode in your Bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How to deactivate inline mode in your Bot? When you talk to BotFather by /help he doesn't give any instructions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Type `/setinline`, choose bot to disable inline mode, that type `/empty`. This will disable inline mode in your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/setinline` and then `/setnoinline` command to disable inline mode.