# Telegram bot error: I am not able to send its username

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

When I try to send my Telegram bot's username in any chat (e.g. writing @myBotName_bot in a chat with a friend of mine) Telegram does not allow me to do it: there's a cross instead of the standard blue send button.
Also something unexpected happens: when I write its username, `result.get("message")` returns null (where `result` is a JSON object).

I really would like to share here some code to respect SO's policies, but I don't know where the problem may be (and I think it's more about some configuration) but I've found nothing about that on the internet, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Resolved***

If interested, it's how I resolved: it's a setting in BotFather, called `inline`

See this question -> [How to deactivate inline mode in your Bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099589/how-to-deactivate-inline-mode-in-your-bot)